# Преобразовать массив strptime в строку

Tags: php, дата

Имеется массив, полученный из функции "strptime", следующего вида:

```
Array
(
    [tm_sec] => 0
    [tm_min] => 0
    [tm_hour] => 11
    [tm_mday] => 26
    [tm_mon] => 3
    [tm_year] => 0
    [tm_wday] => 4
    [tm_yday] => 115
    [unparsed] => 
)
```

Необходимо ее преобразовать в строку вида `"%Y-%m-%G %H:%M:%S"`

Как это можно сделать в php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Взято с просторов ([ссылка](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strptime.php#68792)):

```
$outformat =  '%Y-%m-%G %H:%M:%S';  
$unxTimestamp = mktime( 
    $arr['tm_hour'], 
    $arr['tm_min'], 
    $arr['tm_sec'], 
    1 , 
    $arr['tm_yday'] + 1, 
    $arr['tm_year'] + 1900 
);
echo strftime($outformat , $unxTimestamp);
```

Где `$arr` твой массив из `strptime`